# How to trigger functions to save and load worldMap data while using RealityKit, ARKit and SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, arkit, realitykit, world-map

I’m building an augmented reality app with **RealityKit**, ARKit and **SwiftUI**.
The content view has a ZStack that contains the ARView and the Swift views layered over it.

More specifically the ARView is there as  ARContentView()— a swift view that wraps the ARViewContainer(), which in itself represents the ARView in RealityKit.

I’m adding photos of the code below.

[contentView with ZStack that includes layered UI Views and ARContentView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq2y5.png)

The goal is for the user to be able to save and load the **worldMap** data so as to **persist the AR experience** after they close and reopen their app.

The **problem** is that I’m trying to **trigger the functions to save and to load the world map** data by clicking on buttons in the SwiftUI views, and these buttons have to trigger the functions to save and load world map data in the ARView.

I **can** trigger the code to save the worldMap data **from within the ARView by adding gestures to the view (eg swiping up)**, as seen below, *but I need to actually link these functions from within the Content View buttons*.

WHAT IS REALLY CONFUSING ME :

Because the ARView is already defined by Apple and I can only add functionality to it by extending it and adding new functions, I can’t add a binding variable to it that keeps up with the state of events in the Content View (since stored variables can’t be added to extensions).

[an example of one of the functions that uses the current AR session to interact with the world map object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cABU.png)

How can I trigger these different ARView dependent actions within the parent SwiftUI view that contains the ARContentView in it’s ZStack?

Likewise … The question remains the other way around, **when an event takes place in the ARView, how can I send the returned info back to the SwiftUI content view so it can make a change in its state variables and trigger an animation?** (this could be a separate question but the basis for the problem is still connecting between these two types of views)

The ARViewContainer struct that comes for free with initiating a new Augmented Reality RealityKit project has a couple of functions - makeUIView() and updateUIView() baked into them, but I haven’t found any tutorials on how to use the updateUIView() function.

[Image of ARContainerView taking in a var for construction plus the functions within it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CZgb.png)

I’m wondering if it the updateUIView() function within ARContainerView struct is there to solve the issue I’m having of **connectivity between these layers, if so how to use it, and if not how else to solve the problem ?**

Please let me know if anything is unclear.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to coordinate between your `SwiftUI` view and the `UIViewRepresentable` that houses your `ARView`, you use a `ARViewCoordinator` and `ARSessionDelegate` to pass the data between them. When I have time I will load up an example or you can check out Reality School on Youtube for a tutorial.